# MBeanServerConnection.invoke hangs forever

Tags: timeout, jmx, invoke, freeze, mbeans

We have an app that invokes various remote methods on MBeans using MBeanServerConnection.invoke.
Occasionally one of these methods hangs.
Is there any way to have a timeout on the call?  so that it will return with an exception if the call takes too long?

Or do I have to move all those calls into separate threads so they don't lock up the UI and require killing the app?

Answer (score 3):

See http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2007/05/making_a_jmx_co.html

**=====  Update  =====**

I was thinking about this stuff when I first responded, but I was on my mobile and I can't type worth a damn on it.....

This is really an RMI problem, and unless you use a different protocol, there's not much you can do, except, as you say, move all those calls into separate threads so they don't lock up the UI.

But.... if you have the option of fiddling with the target server and you can customize  the connecting client, you have at least 1 option which is to customize the  [JMXConnectorServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnectorServer.html) on your target servers.

The standard JMXConnectorServer implementation is the [RMIConnectorServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/rmi/RMIConnectorServer.html). Part of it's specification is that when you create a new instance using any of the constructors (like [RMIConnectorServer(JMXServiceURL url, Map environment)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/rmi/RMIConnectorServer.html#RMIConnectorServer%28javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL,%20java.util.Map%29)), the **environment** map can contain a key/value pair where the key is [RMIConnectorServer.RMI_CLIENT_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/remote/rmi/RMIConnectorServer.html#RMI_CLIENT_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE) and the value is a [RMIClientSocketFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/rmi/server/RMIClientSocketFactory.html). Therefore, you can specify a socket factory method like this:

```
RMIClientSocketFactory clientSocketFatory = new RMIClientSocketFactory() {
   public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) {
      Socket s = new Socket(host, port);
      s.setSoTimeout(3000);
   }
};
```

This factory creates a [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) and then sets its [SO_TIMEOUT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_TIMEOUT) using [setSoTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29), so when the client connects using this socket, *all* operations, including connecting, will timeout after 3000 ms.

You could also checkout the [JMXMP](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK/tree/master/OpenDMK/jmx-optional/src/main/java/javax/management/remote/jmxmp) connector and server in the jmx-optional package of the [OpenDMK](https://github.com/nickman/OpenDMK). (links are to my github mavenized). No built in solution, mind you, but they're super easy to extend and JMXMP is simple TCP socket based rather than RMI, so this type of customization would be trivial.

Cheers.

Comment: Seems to come down to "move the work to threads you can kill/ignore".

Comment: Thanks, that does look helpful.

Comment: I wonder if the same can be done when we start out with a Spring `MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean`, which in turn yields a `MBeanServerConnection`.

Comment: Sure. You need to have the **jmx-optional.jar** in your classpath, and then simply use the JMXMP ServiceURL, e.g. *service:jmx:jmxmp://yourhost:port*.

Answer (score 1):

@ Nicholas : The above code is not working.I mean request is not getting timeout after 3000. ms.

map.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_CLIENT_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE , new RMIClientSocketFactory() {

```
            @Override
            public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
                if(logger.isInfoEnabled() ){
                    logger.info("JMXManager inside createSocket..." + host + ": port :" + port);
                    }
                  Socket s = new Socket(host, port);
                  s.setSoTimeout(3000);
                  return s;
            }
        });

        cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url,map,mbeanServer);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I answered on: [How to set request timeout for JMX Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791025/how-to-set-request-timeout-for-jmx-connector/) the RMI properties can help you. All the properties are on Oracle documentation site:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html.

For example: `-Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=60000` is a client side tcp response timeout. There are also properties for connect timeout and for server side connections.

I also am not happy how the JMX/RMI/TCP stack hides important settings from lower level protocols, and makes it not available for a single connection.